# Float Two Divs Side By Side And Keep Constant Distance Between Them

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, footer

In my website footer I have two divs that I've floated left and right using flexbox, with the below CSS. It looks alright on mobile, except the problem I have is when maximising the screen the distance between the two divs grows larger. Is there a way to keep the distance between both of them the same, so they don't widen when the screen is enlarged? I want to keep them in the centre of the screen.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative;">

    <div id="left" style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: center;">
      <p><b>Leeds</b><br />
        <br>
        Suite 1<br />
        5th Floor <br />
        31/32 Park Row <br />
        Leeds <br />
        England<br />
        LS1 5JD<br />
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: center;">
      <p><b>Kuala Lumpur</b><br />
        <br>
        Level 16<br />
        Jalan Stesen Sentral 5<br />
        1 Sentral<br />
        KL Sentral<br />
        50470 Kuala Lumpur<br />
        Malaysia<br />
        <br />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, and tweak the padding with the media queries as you wish:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #282E34;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
     <p><b>Leeds</b><br />
        <br>
        Suite 1<br />
        5th Floor <br />
        31/32 Park Row <br />
        Leeds <br />
        England<br />
        LS1 5JD<br />
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p><b>Kuala Lumpur</b><br />
        <br>
        Level 16<br />
        Jalan Stesen Sentral 5<br />
        1 Sentral<br />
        KL Sentral<br />
        50470 Kuala Lumpur<br />
        Malaysia<br />
        <br />
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- use justify content property to align it close to eacch other -->
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  justify-content: end !important;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: start !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. In this case you could even use a code snippet and add some example html to provide a demonstration that uses the css you are showing.